# How to get the details of the user deleted in keycloak using AdminEvent

Tags: java, spring, redhat, keycloak, keycloak-services

i have below code that gets executed when an admin is creating or deleting a user in the keycloak UI.
Through the help of the adminEvent: http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/server_admin/topics/events/admin.html
Creating a user returns the user details via adminEvent.getRepresentation().
However when deleting a user returns me a null.

This is also the same when deleting a role, deleting a group or deleting a user_session.(ResourceTypes)

My question is how can i retrieve the deleted details?

```
import org.keycloak.events.admin.AdminEvent;
import org.keycloak.models.UserModel;

public void handleResourceOperation(AdminEvent adminEvent, UserModel user) {

        MQMessage queueMessage = new MQMessage();
        queueMessage.setIpAddress(adminEvent.getAuthDetails().getIpAddress());
        queueMessage.setUsername(user.getUsername());

        switch (adminEvent.getOperationType()) {
        case CREATE:
            LOGGER.info("OPERATION : CREATE USER");
            LOGGER.info("USER Representation : " + adminEvent.getRepresentation());
            String[] split = adminEvent.getRepresentation().split(",");
            queueMessage.setTransactionDetail("Created user " + split[0].substring(12));
            sendQueueMessage(adminEvent, queueMessage);
            break;
        case DELETE:
            LOGGER.info("OPERATION : DELETE USER");
            LOGGER.info("USER Representation : " + adminEvent.getRepresentation());
            queueMessage.setTransactionDetail("User has been deleted.");
            sendQueueMessage(adminEvent, queueMessage);
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you got the answer by now. Sharing the solution that may be helpful for others. User details can be captured  in `postInit` method of EventListenerProviderFactory as below,

```
public class UserEventListenerProviderFactory implements EventListenerProviderFactory {

@Override
public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
    return new UserEventListenerProvider(keycloakSession);
}

@Override
public void init(Config.Scope scope) {
}

@Override
public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {
    
    keycloakSessionFactory.register(
            (event) -> {
                if (event instanceof UserModel.UserRemovedEvent) {
                    UserModel.UserRemovedEvent dEvent = (UserModel.UserRemovedEvent) event;
                    //TODO YOUR LOGIC WITH `dEvent.getUser()`
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void close() {

}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return "sample_event_listener";
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately `getFirstAttribute` method doesn't work correctly. When user delete himself everything is correct, I can check his email and all of his custom attributes. The problem is when user is deleted by the admin panel or admin API. Then I can see his email or id but for some reason not attributes.